# Angular momentum and the $S$-matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, s-matrix-theory

I have been curious about the status of angular momentum in the context of the $S$-matrix and scattering amplitudes. In particular, if we pass to a classical scattering problem and imagine scattering particles in from infinity, the momenta of the particles are obviously not enough to specify the angular momentum-- if we have e.g. two incoming particles with momenta $p$, $-p$ in the center of mass frame, the angular momentum will classically be related to the distance at closest approach between the two particles, in addition to their momenta. This data cannot be obtained directly from the momenta of the particles at infinity, by itself.

One might suspect that one can wave away this effect because of the uncertainty principle-- after all if we know the ingoing and outgoing momenta with infinite precision we have zero information about the positions of the particles at infinity. But of course this is not the case-- the squared angular momentum operator should commute with the Hamiltonian and thus should be simultaneously diagonalizable with the momentum eigenstates. It thus seems like in principle we might be able to consider a "total angular momentum" quantum number for our scattering amplitudes, even in cases where the scattered particles have zero spin.

So my question is-- how does the information about the total angular momentum enter into scattering amplitudes of spinless particles?

Comment: Have you considered simply choosing to work with spherical harmonics? It will automatically solve the problem you are thinking about, and is also the standard way to do things. The conversion from the plane wave basis to the spherical harmonics is a chore, but at least it is a part of the standard toolbox for theoretical physicists. The difficulty, however, is that it can get unwieldy because we tend to use QFT for particle physics, which is more interested in beams, not angular momentum eigenstates. Simply not convenient enough. There wont be physics changes.

Comment: As already suggested, you can work with partial waves, that is decompose the initial as well as the final two-particle states in Lorentz irreps that are labeled by the total spin of the pair, $\ell$L among other labels. In the classical limit  it is not difficult to see that the partial wave is well approximated by the classical value $\ell=b p$, where b is the impact parameter obtained by the 2D Fourier tr. of the amplitude wrt momentum transferred $q$. Look up eikonal scattering for more details when  the particles have a nearly defined trajectory, e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.00085

Comment: You might be interested in: "On the General Theory of Collisios for Particles with Spin", by M. Jacob and G.C. Wick (1959) https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(59)90051-X